# Can I write a plugin for iOS to override functionality

Tags: ios, iphone, plugins

Can I write a separate plugin iOS app, which can add functionality of Parent app.
Suppose, I have a parent iOS app, that basically adds a customer with Name, Address field.
Now Can I create a new iOS app that define a UI for adding Phone Number field, and when someone press save button on my Parent Application, it invokes plugin apps UI to get the Field data.

Comment: Theoretically yes. But it will have a very weird user experience hopping back and forth between apps. And it might even conflict with the apple review guidelines if your first app *requires* the second app and simply does not work without it.

Comment: @luk2302, If I don't want to move back and forth, then Is it possible.

Comment: Then I do not understand what you mean with "plugin".

Comment: @luk2302, Suppose I have a parent App say A, In A have a button to save Employee.
Now, I want to open a Form with With some more fields that were not available in parent App A.
So Can I write a new Application that contains the UI part of Form capturing new fields, And when I click on Save button in Parent A, I can invoke this Form inside the Parent App A.
Can I Do that ?